# Property [post] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I have cart table

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('post_id')
    ->references('id')->on('posts')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->timestamps();
```

and cart model

```php
protected $guarded = [];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::Class);
}

protected $fillable = [
    'post_id', 'user_id',
];

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::Class);
}
```

I want to sum the `price` column. I tried more than one way but it didn't work. I tried like this:

cartController

```php
$totalprice = $user->carts->post->sum('price');
return view('cart.cart',compact('user', 'totalprice'));
```

Does anyone have a solution to show the total price?

Comment: It looks like your `carts` is a collection and not a single instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says in the error: It's a `Collection` instance.

Meaning, it holds more than one `Cart` instances and you have to map (loop) through these objects.

```
$totalprice = $user->carts()->with(['post'])->get()
           ->reduce(function($carry, $cart) {
               return $carry + floatval($cart->post->price);
           }, 0);

$totalprice = number_format( $totalprice, 2, '.' );
```

I'm using `with` because there could be n number of carts and it is good to eager load them in advance as to prevent extra db calls. Finally reducing the collection to totalprice.